# Which pattern uses in gsub! to replace ordered list (li tag) html string with order number

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I have an html string as below:

```
<ol><li>CNN</li><li>BBC</li><li>Reuters</li></ol>
```

I need to convert this string to plain text use gsub! method of Ruby. Result will be as below

```
1) CNN 2) BBC 3) Reuters
```

Like this, i handle convert H1-H6:

```
text.gsub!(/(<\/h[1-6]>)/i, "\n\\1") # move closing tags to new lines
    text.gsub!(/[\s]*<h([1-6]+)[^>]*>[\s]*(.*)[\s]*<\/h[1-6]+>/i) do |s|
      hlevel = $1.to_i

      htext = $2
      htext.gsub!(/<br[\s]*\/?>/i, "\n") # handle <br>s
      htext.gsub!(/<\/?[^>]*>/i, '') # strip tags

      # determine maximum line length
      hlength = 0
      htext.each_line { |l| llength = l.strip.length; hlength = llength if llength > hlength }
      hlength = line_length if hlength > line_length
      hlength = 3

      case hlevel
        when 1   # H1, equal below
          htext = htext.upcase + "\n" + ('=' * hlength)
        when 2   # H1, dashes below
          htext = htext.upcase + "\n" + ('-' * hlength)
        else     # H3-H6, dashes below
          htext = htext + "\n" + ('-' * hlength)
      end

      "\n" + htext
    end
```

input :

```
<h1>heading 1</h1></div><h2>heading 2</h2><h3>heading 3</h3><h4>heading 4</h4>
```

output:

```
HEADING 1
=== 
HEADING 2
--- 
heading 3
--- 
heading 4
---
```

Anybody can help me, Thanks

Comment: Is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 relevant to your question, or is your question related to a sufficiently-limited case that you don't expect the mentioned issued to be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '<ol><li>CNN</li><li>BBC</li><li>Reuters</li></ol>'
s.gsub(/<ol>(.*)<\/ol>/) {        # search for OL
  $counter = 0                    # init counter
  $~[1].gsub(/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/) { # search for LI within result
    '' + ($counter += 1).to_s + ') ' + $~[1] + ' '  
  } 
}.strip                           # remove trailing space

#⇒ "1) CNN 2) BBC 3) Reuters"
```

Hope it helps.